# WPF Bluring main form when showing dialogs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So i've added blureffect on main grid of main form:

```
 <Grid.Effect>
    <BlurEffect x:Name="MainGridBlur" Radius="0" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
 </Grid.Effect>
```

and added custom method for opening dialogs on main form:

```
    public Window CreateDialogWindow(Window window)
    {
        window.Owner = this;
        window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;

        MainGridBlur.Radius = 10;
        window.ShowDialog();
        MainGridBlur.Radius = 0;

        return window;
    }
```

This is how i'm calling this method from other forms when they are creating dialogs:

```
((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).CreateDialogWindow(new SomeDialog());
```

My question is, is there any better way to do this?

Comment: We use dialogs in mvvm app, but we would instead create an interface for dialog class. Register this interface with something like unity, then ask the unity to resolve whenever we need this dialog (through dependency injection) and then just use it. This way we only have a dependency on an interface. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: My case is similar. I designed a Window in advance and call showdialog() method. And I give blur effect to parent Window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this answer is super late, but better late than never, right?
I managed to do it by catching WndProc messages WM_SETFOCUS and WM_KILLFOCUS and bluring form on WM_KILLFOCUS and de-bluring (??) on WM_SETFOCUS.

```
    using System.Windows.Interop;

    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }


    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        switch (msg)
        {
            case 8: //WM_KILLFOCUS
                MainGridBlur.Radius = 10;
                break;
            case 7: //WM_SETFOCUS
                MainGridBlur.Radius = 0;
                break;
        }
        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Hope this helps someone.

EDIT.
I just realised i could use Got/LostKeyboardFocus events to achieve same thing, here is an example:

```
    private void Main_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGridBlur.Radius = 0;
    }

    private void Main_LostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainGridBlur.Radius = 10;
    }
```

Comment: Late answers are as useful as new ones, don't worry about it:) Stack Overflow plans for the long run.